# How you use deltatime in raylib?

Tags: c, timedelta, raylib

Can anyone please confirm if this is how you use deltatime in raylib using `GetFrameTime()`. If not, then how exactly?

```
#include <raylib.h>

int main(void)
{
    InitWindow(800, 450, "sample");

    Rectangle rec = {100, 100, 50, 50};

    SetTargetFPS(60);
    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        float dt = GetFrameTime()*GetFPS();

        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT))
            rec.x += 5*dt;

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(BLACK);
            DrawRectangleRec(rec, RED);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code which I tried.

Comment: Wouldn't it be *just* `GetFrameTime()`? That's the time elapsed since the last frame. By multiplying it with the current FPS, you would just get a value close to `1`.